# I'm getting the data multiple times , when I'm subscribing behavior subject from service in angular 14

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, behaviorsubject

I have a behavior subject in main component  when the user click on update button it will emit true/false based on the condition.

That behavior subject is subscribed in another component and based on that true/false I need to show or hide rows.

Problem is behavior subject variable is emitted only one time in main but subscribed multiple times in other component.

my code :
in service.ts

```
      public sendToRenderer = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
      public recievedData=this.sendToRenderer.asObservable();
      changeData(data: boolean) {
      this.sendToRenderer.next(data)
      }
```

tried with subject also like below:(but same response)

```
      public sendToRenderer = new Subject<boolean>();
      public recievedData=this.sendToRenderer.asObservable();
      changeData(data: boolean) {
      this.sendToRenderer.next(data)
      }
```

in main component.ts

```
       onUpdate(e: any) {
           this.uploadService.changeData(this.isRemarksUpdated)
            //this.isRemarksupdated is comning as true/false from other method
         }
```

in other component.ts

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscripition= this.uploadService.recievedData.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.ispreFundEdited=data
      })
    }
```

when I'm using  this.ispreFundEdited in any other method coming as *undefined* for the first time then coming true/false

here data getting multiple times like below (false/true)

[image: 6 false]

what I have tried :

I have tried with using pipe like *".pipe(take(1)).subscribe(()=>{})"*, but no luck.

Comment: How often is `onUpdate` getting called? Also, strongly suggest you don't "staticize" the data into a local variable, even less so using a `subscribe` callback. Suggest using pipeable operators and generating an Observable in the component. You would then use the `async` pipe to subscribe to that Observable

Answer (score 0):

`this.ispreFundEdited` can be `undefined` if you use it before the assignment in `subscribe((data) => ...)` happens.

Possible reasons why you see the data multiple times:

1. You call `onUpdate` multiple times.
2. You don't unsubscribe from your subscription.
3. You reuse your other component multiple times. Use `shareReplay` or `share` in your service depending on your use case:
   `public recievedData$ = this.sendToRenderer.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay(1));`